# keyStore.getKey() returns NULL

Tags: certificate, key, keystore

I want to sign a PDF with a self generated certificate. In this process I need a keystore and private key. The signing will be made with PDFBox by using the class `CreateSignature()`

To generate a keyStore with a self generated certificate I am using this:

```
   public KeyStore generateSampleKeyStoreWith509Certificate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

    X509Certificate cert;
    PrivateKey caKey;

    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        caKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

        Date notBefore = new Date();
        Date notAfter = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo spkInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
        X509v3CertificateBuilder newGen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name(issuer), serial, notBefore,
                notAfter, new X500Name(subject), spkInfo);
        ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").setProvider("BC")
                .build(caKey);
        X509CertificateHolder certHolder = newGen.build(sigGen);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(certHolder.getEncoded());
        cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is1);
        is1.close();

    } catch (OperatorCreationException | CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchProviderException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, password);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("SelfSigned", cert);

    return keyStore;
}
```

The certificate is entered correctly, but shouldn't there be a key, too? Or am I wrong that the keystore should be holding a key?

I'm just figuring this sibject, so I'm thankful of every bit of help.

Comment: According to the javadoc of `getKey()`, "The key must have been associated with the alias by a call to setKeyEntry, or by a call to setEntry with a PrivateKeyEntry or SecretKeyEntry."

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and meanwhile I added that line and it works. But as I saw some examples on the internet without it I was wondering if I'm missing something, or if so many examples are missleading.

Comment: Then please answer your question yourself. IMHO it is interesting to have some working code for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 X509Certificate[] certChain = new X509Certificate[1];
 certChain[0] = cert;

 keyStore.setKeyEntry("SelfSigned",caKey, password, certChain);
```

Adding the above code, at the bottom, enters the privateKey previously created to the keystore. It seems most examples on the internet assume loading a keystore with privatekey already entered before.